# Посчитать количество значений, в которых не содержится одно тире

Tags: python, счетчики

Программа выводит из списка все значения, в которых не содержится одного тире "-". Код программы:

```
food_table = {
    "1": "виноградное варенье",
    "2": "-",
    "3": "слива, черемуха и черешня",
    "4": "свежий апельсин",
    "5": "-",
    "6": "ломтики арбуза и дыни",
    "7": "-",
    "8": "йогурт с вишней",
    "9": "-",
    "10": "яблочный пирог",
    "11": "рататуй из кабачков",
    "12": "варенная картошка с грибами",
    "13": "-",
    "14": "персик без косточки",
    "15": "-"
}
for key, value in food_table.items():
    if value == "-":
        pass
    else:
        print(f"{key}. {value}")
```

В списке `9 значений без тире` и `6 значений с тире`. Нужно **посчитать количество** ключей или значений, в которых **не содержится "-"**.

Comment: если в одной ветке условного оператора написано pass, то очевидно, что эта ветка не нужна (и только мешает чтению кода). А раз не нужна, то нужно изменить условие на обратное, чтобы избавиться от pass

Comment: @Эникейщик Спасибо! Исправил на `if value != "-":        print(f"{key}. {value}")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
food_table = {
    "1": "виноградное варенье",
    "2": "-",
    "3": "слива, черемуха и черешня",
    "4": "свежий апельсин",
    "5": "-",
    "6": "ломтики арбуза и дыни",
    "7": "-",
    "8": "йогурт с вишней",
    "9": "-",
    "10": "яблочный пирог",
    "11": "рататуй из кабачков",
    "12": "варенная картошка с грибами",
    "13": "-",
    "14": "персик без косточки",
    "15": "-"
}

# Обьявляем переменную, хранящую в себе количество значений в словаре, несодержащие в себе "-"
count_without_dash = 0 

for key, value in food_table.items():
    if value == "-":
        pass
    else:
        count_without_dash += 1 # увеличиваем количество значений в словаре без "-" на единицу
        print(f"{key}. {value}")

# Выводим количество значений в словаре без "-"
print(f"В {count_without_dash} значениях не содержится \"-\"")
```

Вывод:

> В 9 значениях не содержится "-"

Answer (score 3):

Однострочник:

```py
print(sum(x != "-" for x in food_table.values()))
```

Но у меня есть два замечания:

- Словарь - это не список, это разные типы данных, у вас данные в словаре
- Содержит и равно - это разный вид проверок, у вас проверка на равенство, а не на вхождение (содержание)

Comment: Спасибо за замечания! Нужно чтобы ключ и значение так же выводились `print(f"{key}. {value}")`, если добавлю ваш код, то это будет второй цикл.

Comment: Просто в заголовке вопроса написано только про подсчет, да, я пропустил насчёт вывода, что он тоже нужен )